# Partial integration problem in calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

This is a problem that I have in my calculus class. However I don't know how to solve it. I was wondering if anyone has some tips on solving the problem.

Given this information:
$f\left(0\right)=b,\:f\left(2\right)=0,\:f'\left(x\right)=\cos \left(x^5\right),$

Solve: $\int x^3\cdot f\left(x\right)dx$

I'm supposed to use partial integration here, but I am just stuck. Any tips or hints would be awesome! Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Use partial integration!

Comment: With integration by parts, you differentiate part of the function and integrate the rest.  Which can you do with f(x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}&\int x^3 f(x)\;\text{d}x \;\;=\;\; \frac{x^4}{4} \cdot f(x) \;-\; \int \frac{x^4}{4} \cdot \cos(x^5)\;\text{d}x\\[5mm] =\;\;& \frac{x^4}{4} \cdot f(x) \;-\; \frac{1}{5 \cdot 4}\int5x^4 \cdot \cos(x^5)\;\text{d}x \\[5mm] =\;\;& \frac{x^4}{4} \cdot f(x) \;-\; \frac{1}{20}\int^{x^5}\cos(x)\;\text{d}x \\[5mm] =\;\;& \frac{x^4}{4} \cdot f(x) \;-\; \frac{1}{20}\cdot\sin(x^5)\end{aligned} $$

Integrating $\;f'(x)\;$ to get $\;f(x)\;$ is beyond me though; I hope this helps.